# Spinnaker hal is not starting due to java version

Tags: java, macos, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I couldn't start hal in my local mac, I was having java8 before, Now I have upgrade to java11, still I see the same error.

````
Muthus-MBP-2:~ muthukumar$ hal -v
The halyard daemon isn't running yet... starting it manually........................................................
Waiting for halyard to start timed out after 122 seconds
Muthus-MBP-2:~ muthukumar$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode)
Muthus-MBP-2:~ muthukumar$ cd /var/log/spinnaker/halyard/
Muthus-MBP-2:halyard muthukumar$ cat *
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/netflix/spinnaker/halyard/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:601)
Muthus-MBP-2:halyard muthukumar$  ```
````

Comment: Do you have more than one installed JDK on your computer? If you do then maybe you can remove all of them apart from OpenJDK 11?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `JAVA_HOME` env variable is set as halyard may be having issues finding your java install.